# What did Arnold Potterley really want to see in the chronoscope?

Tags: the-dead-past

In Isaac Asimov's "The Dead Past", Arnold convinces Foster to build the chronoscope in his house even though he is afraid that his wife would want to see her dead daughter and

> may find out that maybe their daughter died because of Arnold.

Why did Arnold take that risk? What did he really want to see in the chronoscope?

Comment: I have a hunch that he actually wanted to know if he had stubbed the cigarette or not so that he could be certain of his guilt. Could this be possible?

Comment: If memory serves, I got the impression that Potterley had *no intention* of using the chronoscope to check up on the life (or death) of his own daughter. Instead, at the conscious level, his mind was obsessively focused on clearing up the matter of what the Carthaginians used to do. It was only his wife who, when she saw the opportunity, was eager to watch their daughter in it. (I think this was foreshadowing on Asimov's part to show how the scientists who were main characters had *utterly failed* to grasp the social ramifications of making that tech publicly available.)

Comment: @Manik: Is there anything more that I can add to my answer for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arnold Potterley's stated reason for wanting to view the past was that he was trying to exonerate the Carthaginians of child sacrifice by tossing the children into the flames, with this being a subconscious way of similarly exonerating himself of the death of his daughter.

> Foster paced the floor. Somehow, this explained the reason for Potterley's rabid, irrational desire to boost the
>   Carthaginians, deify them, most of all disprove the story of their fiery sacrifices to Moloch. By freeing them of the guilt of
>   infanticide by fire, he symbolically freed himself of the same guilt.

Arnold believes himself innocent, although he is not entirely certain, but his wife believes in his guilt. Similarly, he believes the Carthaginians to be innocent, but historical belief has condemned them. In both cases, there is a chance that the truth will prove one or both guilty, but there is also a chance that it will prove their innocence. Just to add to that, it's specifically noted that his obsession with Carthage started after his daughter's death, and his wife, helping him with his research, knows about the rumored child sacrifice and asks him to deny it.

> It took a drop of brandy to bring her around. She said, "Is it true? What they did?"
>   "Who did?"
>   "The Carthaginians."
>   He stared at her and she got it out by indirection. She couldn't say it right out.
>
> The Carthaginians, it seemed, worshiped Moloch, in the form of a hollow, brazen idol with a furnace in its belly. At
>   times of national crisis, the priests and the people gathered, and infants, after the proper ceremonies and invocations,
>   were dextrously hurled, alive, into the flames.
>
> They were given sweetmeats just before the crucial moment, in order that the efficacy of the sacrifice not be ruined by
>   displeasing cries of panic. The drums rolled just after the moment, to drown out the few seconds of infant shrieking. The
>   parents were present, presumably gratified, for the sacrifice was pleasing to the gods. . . .
>
> Arnold Potterley frowned darkly. Vicious lies, he told her, on the part of Carthage's enemies. He should have
>   warned her. After all, such propagandistic lies were not uncommon. According to the Greeks, the ancient Hebrews worshiped an ass's head in their
>   Holy of Holies. According to the Romans, the primitive Christians were haters of all men who sacrificed pagan children
>   in the catacombs.
>
> "Then they didn't do it?" asked Caroline.
>   "I'm sure they didn't. The primitive Phoenicians may have. Human sacrifice is commonplace in primitive cultures. But
>   Carthage in her great days was not a primitive culture. Human sacrifice often gives way to symbolic actions such as
>   circumcision. The Greeks and Romans might have mistaken some Carthaginian symbolism for the original full rite, either
>   out of ignorance or out of malice."
>   "Are you sure?"
>   "I can't be sure yet, Caroline, but when I've got enough evidence, I'll apply for permission to use chronoscopy,
>   which will settle the matter once and for all."